# Search bar is missing in mobile theme

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, mobile-web

on-topic page of a help center of a site contains the following sentence:

> Please look around to see if your question has been asked before.

`look around` in above sentence links to the `/search` page where you'll find search bar is missing if you're using mobile theme.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't have asked for a better commit message to end my week on.

[image]

Search bar is now back where it belongs:

[image: screenshot of the fixed /search page]